# Canvas water/blob physics on a circular path with texture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, physics

this is my first question after having relied on this site for years!

Anyway, I'd like to accomplish something similar to this effect:

http://www.flashmonkey.co.uk/html5/wave-physics/

But on a circular path, instead of a horizon. Essentially, a floating circle/blob in the center of the screen that would react to mouse interaction. What I'm not looking for is gravity, or for the circle to bounce around the screen - only surface ripples.

If at all possible I'd like to apply a static texture to the shape, is this a possibility? I'm completely new to Canvas!

I've already tried replacing some code from the above example with circular code from the following link, to very limited success:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/

If only it were that easy :)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to figure out how wave simulation works using View Source and JavaScript console. It's working fine but threw some JS errors. Also, it seems physics update is entangled with rendering in the `render()` method.

Here is what I found about the code:

The `mouseMove()` method creates disturbances on the wave based on mouse position, creating a peak around the mouse. The `target` variable is the index of the particle that needs to be updated, it's calculated from mouse pos.

```
if (particle && mouseY > particle.y) {
    var speed = mouseY - storeY;

    particles[target - 2].vy = speed / 6;
    particles[target - 1].vy = speed / 5;
    particles[target].vy = speed / 3;
    particles[target + 1].vy = speed / 5;
    particles[target + 2].vy = speed / 6;

    storeY = mouseY;
}
```

Then, the particles around `target` are updated. The problem I found is that it does no bounds checking, i.e. it can potentially `particles[-1]` when `target == 0`. If that happens, an exception is thrown, the method call ends, but the code does not stop.

The `render()` method first updates the particle positions, then renders the wave.

Here is its physics code:

```
for (var u = particles.length - 1; u >= 0; --u) {
    var fExtensionY = 0;
    var fForceY = 0;

    if (u > 0) {
        fExtensionY = particles[u - 1].y - particles[u].y - springs[u - 1].iLengthY;
        fForceY += -fK * fExtensionY;
    }

    if (u < particles.length - 1) {
        fExtensionY = particles[u].y - particles[u + 1].y - springs[u].iLengthY;
        fForceY += fK * fExtensionY;
    }

    fExtensionY = particles[u].y - particles[u].origY;
    fForceY += fK / 15 * fExtensionY;

    particles[u].ay = -fForceY / particles[u].mass;
    particles[u].vy += particles[u].ay;
    particles[u].ypos += particles[u].vy;
    particles[u].vy /= 1.04;
}
```

Basically, it's [Hooke's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke's_law) for a chain of particles linked by springs between them. For each particle u, it adds the attraction to the previous and next particles (the if statements check if they are available), to the variable `fForceY`. I don't fully understand the purpose of the `springs` array.

In the last four lines, it calculates the acceleration (force / mass), updates the velocity (add acceleration), then position (add velocity), and finally, reduce velocity by 1.04 (friction).

After the physics update, the code renders the wave:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, stageWidth, stageHeight);
context.fillStyle = color;
context.beginPath();

for (u = 0; u < particles.length; u++) {
    ...
}

...
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

I'm not explaining that, you need to read a canvas tutorial to understand it.

---

Here are some ideas to get started, note that I didn't test these code.

To modify the code to draw a circular wave, we need introduce a [polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), where the particle's `x`-position is the angle in the circle and `y`-position the distance from center. We should use `theta` and `r` here but it requires a large amount of refactoring. We will talk about transforming later.

**`mouseMove()`**: Compute particle index from mouse position on screen to polar coordinates, and make sure the disturbance wrap around:

Define the function (outside `mouseMove()`, we need this again later)

```
 function wrapAround(i, a) { return (i + a.length) % a.length; }
```

Then change

```
 particles[target - 2] --> particles[wrapAround(target - 2, particles)]
 particles[target - 1] --> particles[wrapAround(target - 1, particles)]
 ...
```

The modulo operator does the job but I added `particles.length` so I don't [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) a negative number.

**`render()`**: Make sure the force calculation wrap around, so we need to `wrapAround` function again. We can strip away the two if statements:

```
    fExtensionY = particles[wrapAround(u - 1, particles)].y - particles[u].y - springs[wrapAround(u - 1, springs)].iLengthY;
    fForceY += -fK * fExtensionY;

    fExtensionY = particles[u].y - particles[wrapAround(u + 1, particles)].y - springs[warpAround(u, springs)].iLengthY;
    fForceY += fK * fExtensionY;
```

Here is the result so far in jsfiddle: Notice the wave propagate from the other side. http://jsfiddle.net/DM68M/

After that's done, the hardest part is rendering them on a circle. To do that, we need coordinate transform functions that treat particle's `(x, y)` as `(angle in the circle, distance from center)`, and we also need inverse transforms for mouse interaction in `mouseMove()`.

```
 function particleCoordsToScreenCoords(particleX, particleY) {
   return [ radiusFactor * particleY * Math.cos(particleX / angleFactor),
            radiusFactor * particleY * Math.sin(particleX / angleFactor) ];
 }

 function screenCoordsToParticleCoords(screenX, screenY) {
   // something involving Math.atan2 and Math.sqrt
 }
```

Where the `...Factor` variables needed to be determined separately. The `angleFactor` is two pi over the highest x-position found among particles array

Then, in the coordinates supplied to the `context.lineTo, context.arc`, use the `particleCoordsToScreenCoords` to transform the coordinates.